# Assign a CSS class to a single existing div class rather than to all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, css-selectors, addclass

I'm not sure if im going about this the right way at all but I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do as best I can.

I have a HTML page which contains a menu. Within that menu there are a number of instances where a specific CSS class is being used. When the page changes, a value is passed via URL which is then used to highlight the selected item and expand a submenu.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to use this value to expand the list at the right point, I cant actually select and add a new CSS class or carry out other operations. Ill post some code below so you can maybe get a better understanding of what I'm talking about and then maybe give an example scenario.

```
if (param != null) {
    $('.menuButton')[paramvalue].addClass('on');
    $('.menuButton')[paramvalue].slideDown('normal');
}
```

Thats the javascript part thats giving issues. In the case above, paramvalue could be replaced by a 0 or a 1 etc. This part is reaching the specific class I want to change. I checked this by adding an id to the HTML and retrieving that using:

```
 alert($('.menuButton')[paramvalue].id);
```

This returned the correct ID value.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="menuButton" id="2">Button 1</div>
<div class="subMenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1.3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="menuButton" id="3">Button 2</div>
<div class="subMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There is no CSS to go with the id's they were mainly just added for testing. I can post related CSS if necessary but I don't think its part of the problem.

I should mention that, using the following works

```
$('.menuButton').addClass('on');
```

so maybe that narrows down the issue.

If you need any other info. just ask.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `$(selector)[index]` you are converting a jQuery object to a DOM Element object which has no `addClass` method, you can use `eq()` method instead:

```
$('.menuButton').eq(paramvalue).addClass('on');
$('.menuButton').eq(paramvalue).slideDown('normal');
```

You can also chain your methods:

```
$('.menuButton').eq(paramvalue).addClass('on').slideDown('normal');
```

Comment: May be also worth noting you can use chaining to convert two lines to one. Not really related to the problem, but still, helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot. Had a few other issues with the slideDown part but got it sorted now. I have actually used .eq() a few times before I just forgot about it and assumed what I was doing was actually that. Hopefully I wont forget again :D. At least I can refer back to this if I do.

Comment: @undefined, may I request yeou to have a look at a jquery question on a different topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137404/jquery-find-div-class-name-at-a-certain-position-while-scrolling ?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$('.menuButton').eq(paramvalue).addClass('on');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
$('.menuButton:eq('+paramvalue+')').addClass('on');
```

Which will have a performance gain over selecting all the elements and then cutting them down to just one selected.